# fengyuanchen cropper frame on button click

Tags: jquery, crop

i am using fengyuanchen cropper plugin in a wordpress environment. 
The plugin works if there is a image in the image tag.

What i  need is if i dynamically set the image the crop controls should be displayed(the rectangle)

I have tried multiple ways but nothing seem to be working
eg

```
if($(".attachment-post-thumbnail").attr('src')!=""){
 $('.cropper_Menu1 > img').cropper({
              aspectRatio: 180/293,
              autoCropArea: 1,
              strict: false,
              guides: true,
              highlight: true,
              dragCrop: false,
              cropBoxMovable: false,
              cropBoxResizable: false
            });
}
```

Any Help? Am not good in jquery

I am setting the image

```
$('.inside').bind('DOMNodeInserted DOMNodeDeleted', function(event)  { 
   if($(".attachment-post-thumbnail").attr('src')!=""){
        $("#MenuImg").attr('src',$(".attachment-post-thumbnail").attr('src'));}
});
```

Comment: how you are setting the image dynamically. can you please share that code as well.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using `$.load` event handler like below:

```
$('.inside').bind('DOMNodeInserted DOMNodeDeleted', function(event)  { 
   if($(".attachment-post-thumbnail").attr('src')!=""){
        $("#MenuImg").attr('src',$(".attachment-post-thumbnail").attr('src')).load(function() {
        // Handler for .load() called.
        if($(".attachment-post-thumbnail").attr('src')!=""){
             $('#MenuImg').cropper({
                          aspectRatio: 180/293,
                          autoCropArea: 1,
                          strict: false,
                          guides: true,
                          highlight: true,
                          dragCrop: false,
                          cropBoxMovable: false,
                          cropBoxResizable: false
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: The code works,

The problem for this method is I have 5 different section to be cropped. So duplicating the code is an issue.
Anyway thank you

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. if there is another better solution Please post. Add the build functionality

```
   $('.cropper_Menu1 > img').cropper({
                            aspectRatio: 180/293,
                              autoCropArea: 1,
                              strict: false,
                              guides: true,
                              highlight: true,
                              dragCrop: false,
                              cropBoxMovable: false,
                              cropBoxResizable: false,
                              built: function () 
                              {
                                        $(this).cropper('crop');
                              }
                            });
```